# Mariadb sql query get stuck

Tags: mariadb

I have table `A` which size is 32GB and has the following 5 fields:

- a (int)
- b (varchar(128)
- c (varchar(128)
- d (int)
- e (int)

a, b and c are unique key. Now, when I query like this:

```
select 
  * 
from A 
where 
  (
    (a = 1 and b = "something" and c = "something") 
    || 
    (a = 2 and b = "something1" and c = "something1") 
    || ...
    (a = N and b = "something(N-1)" and c = "something(N-1)")
  )
```

for N = 3000.

When I do explain it says, it using the unique key index, but the query got stuck when I execute. In `processlist` it's state is sending data.

Why this is happening?

**Mysql Explain:**

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------+                     
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                         |                     
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------+                     
|  1 | SIMPLE      | repository_files | range | index_repository_files_on_md5 | index_repository_files_on_md5 | 768     | NULL | 1365 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR |                     
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**MariaDB Explain:**

```
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | repository_files | range | index_repository_files_on_md5 | index_repository_files_on_md5 | 768     | NULL | 224377 | Using index condition; Using where |
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `CPU`, `RAM`, disk config (+ networking if applicable). Structure of table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G`). Have you let it run to completion? If so, how long does it finally take? Is there other activity on the server? Windows or *nix? What do your performance stats say - I'm suspecting disk contention of some sort (usual cause of slowness). When did this problem start to occur? Can we have the real text of the query + the cardinality of the major fields? Please reformat your query using the "code block" option - and not backticks, and please capitalise `SQL` keywords.

Comment: @Vérace there are developers who prefer SQL with all small letters, no capitals ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - sorry about that - I thought it was the standard here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have migrated from mysql to mariadb from that time, it started to happening only for particular table and it is running on Ubuntu server. When this query is running CPU is full.

Comment: Please also add the `EXPLAIN` output and the version of MySQL / MariaDB you use.

Comment: Wow - how long is the query? I'm not surprised that it's slow! How long did it take on the MySQL system? Whenever one sees "strange" queries like that, it's perhaps time to restructure? Split your main table and perform joins?

Comment: @Vérace in MySql server it takes 17 secs to complete, but in Mariadb it takes forever.

Comment: @Vérace is it very slow taking 17 secs to complete for 2536 comparison in 5352523 rows.

Comment: It would be nice if you had added the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE repository_files;`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that

- your MySQL system has 1365 rows
- the `EXPLAIN` for your MariaDB shows 224377 rows
- you're now telling me that your running system has ~500,000
- 535,000 divided by 1365 = ~400
- 400 * 17 = 6800
- 6,800 / 60 = 113 minutes ~ 2 hours

### First thing to try.

Put separate `INDEX`es on b and c and see how that works. If not, try below. Are they reasonably distinct - i.e. is their cardinality high? If they are `UNIQUE`, that would be great.

### Second thing to try.

I suggest that you redesign your table A - you should split it up as I suggested earlier. Maybe you should ask a new question in this regard (pointing back to this thread)? Your query is at least O(n) - or maybe worse? Post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE A\G` and some sample data and we'll try and help you with your new query. Also, give the cardinalities of the important fields.

My suggestion is to keep a, d and e together. Create two new tables B and C and have a `PRIMARY KEY` in those point back to your new `PRIMARY KEY` to your new A. Use a new `AUTO_INCREMENT` as the `PK` for all three. See how that goes.

Comment: Now the current data in production is 5352523 rows. These two explain i took from test server where i dumped few rows and tested. When i do explain in production Mariadb server it say, not using indexes.

Comment: Put the `KEY`s that I suggested and test with **REALISTIC** data.The reason it's not using them is that the optimiser thinks that it's not worth while because of data distribution. p.s. for formatting code, use the "code sample" widget above the edit window.

Comment: I am extremely sorry about that :( . I tried to use it, but when i pasted the output in code block, it was not taking whole thing i pasted there. Thanks a lot for your helps. I will try out what you have suggested.

Comment: I dumped actual data to my test server MySQL server takes the index correctly whereas Mariadb is not taking any index for same data. How this could happen.

Comment: Can you easily change versions? Which version are you using? What made you choose MariaDB in the first place? You mean the **whole** of the data? Which is faster is the important question - not using an index is not necessarily a bad thing!

Comment: Migrated to MariaDB 10.0.23.

Comment: Ya, i dumped whole data from production server to test server.

Comment: Just so we're clear. You have tried my first suggestion (with a full data load) and there has been no speed improvement? Don't worry about whethter it uses indexes or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
create temporary table p 
( a int not null
, b varchar(128) not null
, c varchar(128) not null
,    unique (a,b,c));
```

and then insert the 3000 parameter tuples into this table. The query then becomes:

```
select A.* 
from A
join P
    on A.a = P.a
   and A.b = P.b
   and A.c = P.c
```